# Bootstrap3 switch between Dropdown and Dropup menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootsrtaps Dropdown menu is several places on my website. The only issue I have come across so far is if the drop down is at the bottom then the drop down disappears below the page and an overflow-y appears. Obviously this is not the best, the user has no idea they have to scroll down. I'm dealing with non-technical people here.

I've looked around to see if there was a way to turn the drop down into a drop up when the page hits a certain part of the page, but I could not find anything. Is there anyway to do this with minimal code?

I'm just using a basic bootstrap menu

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

An example of what I am talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/9B8Sj/3/

Comment: This is a known bug / feature-request: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10756

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
    var c = $('.dropdown-menu').offset();
    if(($(window).height()-c.top) < 10) {
        $('.dropdown').addClass('dropup');
    }
});
```

I tested this with your jsfiddle example and it switches the dropdown to a dropup.

Comment: Obviously, I hardcoded the offset for the location check, so you can make that more elegant if you want to.

Comment: How is this working? It seemed like it was working in the fiddle, but when I plugged it into my site it does not want to work. Can you explain what it's trying to accomplish or how to change it to fit any situation?